# comparing null for a number type in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

### html

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="appDeptId" [(ngModel)]="appDeptId"
                    (change)="getAppClinics()">
                    <option [value]=null>Please Select</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let type of appDepartments" [value]="type.deptId">{{type.deptName}}
                    </option>
              </select>
```

### ts

```
appDeptId: number;


getAppClinics(){
 if (this.appDeptId != null) {  // if fails for null
      console.log("this.appDeptId :"+this.appDeptId); // this displays null
}
```

Here even though the value of appDeptId id null, it still enters the if condition and prints null. How can I solve this.

Comment: `this.appDeptId` is not the same as `this.slotSearch.appDeptId`, so maybe that is why you enter the if-statement. Try with `if( this.slotSearch.appDeptId != null)` instead, or try to `console.log(this.appDeptId)`, and you will see that it is not null

Comment: `this.slotSearch.appDeptId` is different than `this.appDeptId`. so probably you are logging a null value from `this.slotSearch.appDeptId`

Comment: @TheNsn666  different variable added in console log by mistake. Question corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You if condition is get null as string so you are comparing `null!='null'` actually so change your condition to

```
if(deviceValue != null && deviceValue != 'null'){
```

should work

[demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-mzhib7)

Answer (score 0):

appDeptId: number;

```
getAppClinics(){
 if (this.appDeptId != null && this.appDeptId != undefined) {  // if fails for null
      console.log("this.appDeptId :"+this.slotSearch.appDeptId); // this displays null
}
```